# Update query in Access very slow

Tags: ms-access, updates, sql-like

I am running the below query on around 100,000 records but it is taking ages, do not know why.

```
UPDATE [tmpMaster] INNER JOIN iMaster ON [tmpMaster].[Name1] like iMaster.mName  & "*" SET [tmpMaster].[iCode] = [iMaster].[iCode];
```

Tried using % instead of * still no change.

Comment: You are using a JOIN that is based on a wildcard LIKE. That alone is slow. Other factors depend on your setup. Do you have a front-end, back-end split? Is your Access file on a network share?

Comment: I had Access database on a Shared location. I moved it to local drive and it is faster then the earlier.  I am  running the query in database itself. Thanks

Comment: Still the overall performance is still slow. I tried extracting unique from 100000 records and update, but since the iMaster has records of around 34000 records, the update query stucks even for less record to update.